# Change url and reload page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like after getting credentials from another website, to change the url in my angularJS application.

I am setting my app like this

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/example', {
    templateUrl: 'views/example.html',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

In my MainCtrl controller I change url like this :

```
$location.url($location.path()); // to remove url query params
$location.path('/example'); // to change the url
```

But this cause Cannot GET /example when I refresh the page.

Is there a solution for this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seams you didn"t handle URL rewriting needed when you activate the HTML5 mode (actually, the /example url doesn't exists, right now the only angular existing url is index.html)

So you'll have to handle URL rewriting server side.. For example for apache in a `.htaccess` file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule !\.\w+$ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or if you're using `grunt-connect` :

```
connect: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            port: 9002,
            hostname: '*',
            middleware: function(connect) {
                return [
                    //modRewrite is used to handle properly angularjs' html5 mode
                    modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]']),
                    lrSnippet,
                    folderMount(connect, '/app')
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing, be carefull, you're doing a double location change. If you want to remove query params, I sugest you to do this :

```
$location.path(url);

// clear any query params
$location.$$search = {};
$location.$$compose();
```